# Converting unstructured data into structured format

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have data of the form: 
`d1 <- c("Name: priya", " Age :47", "Gender : female")`

I want to convert to this form:
`d1 <- c("Name", "Priya", "Age", "47", "Gender", "female")`

How can I do this using R?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not totally clear so I am making some assumptions here.

Supposing your data is like this:
`d1 <- c("Name: Priya", " Age :47"," Gender : female")`

and you want an end result like this:
`d2 <- c("Name", "Priya", "Age", "47", "Gender", "female")`

You could do:
`d2 <-  gsub("\\s","", unlist(strsplit(d1, ":")))`

The `strsplit(d1, ":")` splits each of the quoted elements in d1 by the ":" symbol but outputs a list; unlist converts it to a character vector.
The `gsub` part finds all the spaces `"\\s"` and replaces them with no spaces `""`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trimws` to remove leading or trailing white space, and than `strsplit` with split where you have `:` or  indicated with `[: ]+`.

```
unlist(strsplit(trimws(d1), "[: ]+"))
#[1] "Name"   "priya"  "Age"    "47"     "Gender" "female"
```

or as suggested by @sindri_baldur in the comments

```
trimws(unlist(strsplit(d1, ":")))
```

what has the big advantage to split only at `:` and in case there are spaces in the words it will keep them and remove only leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: or `trimws(unlist(strsplit(d1, ":")))`

Comment: @sindri_baldur that's even more straight forward!